# React-native-maps Zoom

Tags: react-native, survey, react-native-maps

I use longitudeDelta and latitudeDelta for zoom in react native, but they zoom up to a certain point. I need to zoom below cm level. Points that are close to each other appear to be intertwined.I will write the "stake out" function, so I need such a zoom.

here is my zoom func.

```
 const zoomIn = () => {
        const zoomInValue = {
            latitude: region.latitude,
            longitude: region.longitude,
            latitudeDelta: region.latitudeDelta - (region.latitudeDelta / 2),
            longitudeDelta: region.longitudeDelta - (region.longitudeDelta / 2)
        }
       
        setRegion(zoomInValue)
        map.current.animateToRegion(zoomInValue)
      
    }

    const zoomOut = () => {//haritada uzaklasmak icin
        const zoomOutValue = {
            latitude: region.latitude,
            longitude: region.longitude,
            latitudeDelta: region.latitudeDelta + (region.latitudeDelta / 2),
            longitudeDelta: region.longitudeDelta + (region.longitudeDelta / 2)
        }
        setRegion(zoomOutValue)
        map.current.animateToRegion(zoomOutValue)


    }
```